# BST creation in python

Tags: python, data-structures

```
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left=None
        self.right= None

class binoryTree:
    maxi=float('inf')
    mini=-float('inf')
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None

    def insert(self,root,data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root=Node(data)
            print("root data values %s", self.root.data)
        else:
            print("root data values %s", self.root.data)
            if self.root.data>data:
                **if self.root.left is None:
                   self.root.left = Node(data)**
                else:
                    self.insert(self.root.left,data)
            else:   
                if self.root.right is None:
                    self.root.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.insert(self.root.right,data)

    def print_tree(self,root):
        if root is None:
            return
        self.print_tree(root.left)
        print("%d",root.data)
        print("----------")
        self.print_tree(root.right)

    def is_bst(self, root, mini, maxi):
        if root is None:
            return 0
        if root.data <mini and root.data > maxi:
            return 0
        return self.is_bst(root.left,mini,root.data) and self.is_bst(root.right,root.data, maxi)

t= binoryTree()
t.insert(t.root,50)
t.insert(t.root,4)
t.insert(t.root,1)
t.insert(t.root,8)
t.insert(t.root,100)
t.print_tree(t.root)
```

unable to identify the issue in insert function.
Not able to understand why it is not able to go in bold section code after inserting first node.

> [preeti@oc1238606604 data_structures]
>
> > $  /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3 /home/preeti/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 41717 -- /home/preeti/Desktop/code_playground/data_structures/isBst.py

> > root data values %s 50
> > root data values %s 50
> > root data values %s 50
> > root data values %s 50
> > root data values %s 50
> > root data values %s 50
> > root data values %s 50

Getting recursion exceed error since it is calling insert again and again.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up `root` and `self.root`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment, you have mixed up the `self.root` and `root`. The code is not entering the blocked part because you are checking the value of `self.root` which is equal to 50 here, but you needed to check the value of `root` which you were passing as the argument. And a minor issue is that you are using `%s` or `%d` but not using formatting, `,` inside the `print` prints the value after a space, so you should use something like`print("root data values %s".format(root.data))` or `print("root data values %s"%root.data)`

Modified code for insert ->

```
    def insert(self,root,data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root=Node(data)
            print("root data values %d"%self.root.data)
        else:
            print("root data values %s"%root.data)
            if root.data>data:
                if root.left is None:
                   root.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.insert(root.left,data)
            else:   
                if root.right is None:
                    root.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.insert(root.right,data)
```